# Is there a function for random image spawn

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

I'm making a space invader game and I would like to have different invaders spawn. I made the GIFS now I'm just stuck on how to create the RANDOM function so different invaders spawn at random times.

I hope I'm clear enough.

```
turtle.register_shape("L.gif")
turtle.register_shape("D.gif")
turtle.register_shape("M.gif")
turtle.register_shape("R.gif")
turtle.register_shape("Meta.gif")

#Choose a number of enemies
number_of_enemies = 5
#Create an empty list of enemies
enemies = []

#Add enemies to the list
for i in range(number_of_enemies):

#Create the enemy
enemies.append(turtle.Turtle())

for enemy in enemies:
  enemy.color("red")
  enemy.shape("L.gif")
  enemy.penup()
  enemy.speed(0)
  x = random.randint(-200, 200)
  y = random.randint(100, 250)
  enemy.setposition(x,y)
```

Comment: Hi Gabe, we cannot help you if we don't know what is the object "turtle" or "enemy". Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a sketch of how I would have the enemies take on different random images as they are created:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint

# Choose a number of enemies
NUMBER_OF_ENEMIES = 5

ENEMY_IMAGES = ["L.gif", "D.gif", "M.gif", "R.gif"]

screen = Screen()
screen.register_shape("Meta.gif")

for image in ENEMY_IMAGES:
    screen.register_shape(image)

# Create an empty list of enemies
enemies = []

# Add enemies to the list
for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_ENEMIES):

    # Create the enemy
    enemy = Turtle(shape=choice(ENEMY_IMAGES), visible=False)
    enemy.color('red')
    enemy.speed('fastest')

    enemy.penup()
    x = randint(-200, 200)
    y = randint(100, 250)
    enemy.setposition(x, y)
    enemy.showturtle()

    enemies.append(enemy)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It actually works! I've been trying to do this for the past week. The only problem I see now is that whenever I kill one invader the same one respawn. For example when I kill 'L.gif' only 'L.gif' respawn. I was thinking whenever I kill 'X.gif' any 'X.gif' respawn. I hope you understand what I mean. But I'm really grateful for your help thank you!